Do other outputs matter in RNN or only the final output counts?
I'm just exposed to RNN recently. But it's confusing that the network also generates seemingly redundant outputs other than the "hidden states" which are passed as previous memory for the sequential inputs. Here's the picture in question:

As I understand $U$ transform inputs to $h$ an then $h$ is used for generating the "redundant" outputs $\alpha_{1:t}$. My question is: are these outputs useful at all? And in which circumstances?

Autoregressive models are a typical pattern for RNN/LSTM/GRU networks. The goal is to predict element $t$ given elements $1,2,\dots,t-1$ for $t$ from 1 to $T$ the length of the sequence. For instance, this is a standard approach for language models: for each token in the sequence, predict the next token given all the previous tokens.

Auto-regressive. Got it! I heard it but never implement it myself. :D. Thanks
